# Get DayOfQuarter from Date

Tags: mysql

I have a date column in my MySQL database. How do I get dayofquarter from this date?

I have been doing a datediff from the start of the quarter up till now, but would like to be able to do this dynamically.

Comment: Hey Moe, did my insanely awesome answer address your needs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got to do some calculation, but it can definitely be done dynamicly in MySQL alone.  I'll use the date April 30, 2016 (`2016-04-30`) as in the example:

First, here is how you dynamically get the first day of a quarter:

```
SELECT  makedate(YEAR("2016-04-30"), 1) + INTERVAL QUARTER("2016-04-30") QUARTER - INTERVAL 1 QUARTER
```

Once you have this, subtract it from the original date to get the day of quarter for the date and add 1 to it (or the first day would be day 0)

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF("2016-04-30",(makedate( YEAR ("2016-04-30"), 1) + INTERVAL QUARTER("2016-04-30") QUARTER - INTERVAL 1 QUARTER)) + 1 AS dayofquarter
```

To be dynamic, replace all three  `2016-04-30` dates with the date column in the table you're querying from:

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF(`somedatecolumn`,(makedate( YEAR (`somedatecolumn`), 1) + INTERVAL QUARTER(`somedatecolumn`) QUARTER - INTERVAL 1 QUARTER)) + 1 AS dayofquarter FROM `my_table`
```

If you're looking for a simple, snazzy, built-in function like `DAYOFQUARTER(somedate)`, your out of luck, you'll need to create your own http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html